# Error after adding a dependency to an Android application

Tags: java, android, maven, dependencies, dalvik

I'm developing an Android application and I'm trying to add a dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm not even using it anywhere, but after I add that dependency, when I try to run the application, I get an error:

```
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1


 Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
 when not building a core library.
```

Why can't I run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try excluding both stax, stax-api and xpp3 from the simple import as explained here: 
[Android: error including/repacking dependencies which reference javax core classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964668/android-error-including-repacking-dependencies-who-reference-javax-core-classes)

Comment: Well, actually now when I try to use this library, I'm getting  errors like: 11-12 19:15:16.636: I/dalvikvm(846): Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.<init>
It seems that javax.xml.stream.* was included in that excluded libraries... now I have no idea what to do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Dalvik/Android does not allow using javax.* packages. You have to either shade all of them e.g. with the Maven Shade Plugin or better use a dependency that does not do that.

There might be an android specific version of the simple-xml library available. If you need it for soap webservices you might want to take a look at [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) instead.