# Android: Remove Stax dependencies from Simplexml in build.xml for command-line build

Tags: android, ant, xml-parsing

I have exactly the same issue as was answered here for a Maven Android project.
However I have to work with a command-line Android build system, which uses a build.xml in the project ( which is a library project.)

I tried a toy project with simplexml in Eclipse
and it all seem to work automagically. However, I've no idea what I should put in the
command line build.xml file to achieve the same thing... I've only a passing acquaintance with
ant....
thanks

[Android: error including/repacking dependencies which reference javax core classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964668/android-error-including-repacking-dependencies-which-reference-javax-core-class)

Answer (score 0):

I had another look at this code, and I see that it was the "proguard" stuff that
was failing.

So I added this to proguard.cfg

and the code at least compiled then. Haven't had a chance to see if it works yet.

-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**